# How to pass 2 array in foreach using $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert dynamic form filed values into the database. To insert these values in database,I am trying to apply foreach loop in MySQL query
The code goes like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
if  ($_POST['elements'],$_POST['quanity']){
foreach($_POST['elements'] as $elements){
    foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $quantity){
    $sql[] = "INSERT INTO create_campaign (elements, quantity) VALUES ('{$elements}','{$quantity}')";
}
}

   foreach($sql as $query){
  mysql_query($query);
}
}
```

}

```
<div class="row col-md-12" ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                                                    <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" name="records">
                                                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Elements</label>
                                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
                                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Campaign Name" ng-model="choice.name" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="elements[]" multiple> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Quantity</label>
                                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
                                                           <select class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme"  name="quantity[]">
                                                             <option value="1">100</option>
                                                             <option value="2">200</option>
                                                             <option value="3">300</option>
                                                             <option value="4">400</option>

                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                     <button type="button" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" ng-click="addNewChoice()" id="add_field">add</button>
                                                     <button   ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" >Remove</button>
                                                     </fieldset>  
                                                </div>   
                                           </div>
                                        </div>

                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="description">
                                      </div>
                                        <input class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit_val">
```

It's giving error and insertion of the database is not happening, what do I do?

Comment: What your are trying to achieve..?

Comment: Don't use queries inside loop.

Comment: You're missing a `}` for starters...

Comment: I tried that as well but no insertion takes place.

Comment: Then whats the error?

Comment: @dat3450 error:  syntax error, unexpected ','

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like as follows.. You can get perfect error if stuck by this...

```
        <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
    if  ($_POST['elements'] && $_POST['quantity']){
        foreach($_POST['elements'] as $elements){
             foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $quantity){
                 echo $sql = "INSERT INTO create_campaign (elements, quantity) VALUES ('{$elements}','{$quantity}')";
                //mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error); 
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
<div class="row col-md-12" ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" name="records">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Elements</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Campaign Name" ng-model="choice.name" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="elements[]" multiple>
        </div>
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Quantity</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
            <select class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme"  name="quantity[]">
                <option value="1">100</option>
                <option value="2">200</option>
                <option value="3">300</option>
                <option value="4">400</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" ng-click="addNewChoice()" id="add_field">add</button>
        <button   ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" >Remove</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="description">
</div>
<input class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit_val">
</form>
```

Comment: and also use `mysqli` instead of 'mysql'

Comment: @user7939485 , Now Code works... and you forgot for add <form> tag before and after html

Comment: No, Still data is not inserting into database

Comment: please add <form> tag before and after. in html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152589/discussion-between-user7939485-and-dhruvang).